# Grouping in sql on level base by assigning level on runtime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and some data in it. I want to assign Level to each account.

```
DROP TABLE COA;

CREATE TABLE COA
(
    ID NUMERIC NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    COACode VARCHAR(50),
    COATitle VARCHAR(50),
    ParentCode NUMERIC,
    DebitAmount NUMERIC(30),

    CONSTRAINT FK_COAParentCode 
        FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES COA(ID)
);

INSERT INTO COA VALUES (1, '01', 'Expenses', NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (2, '02', 'Assets', NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (3, '03', 'Bills', NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (4, '01-01', 'Salary Expenses', 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (5, '01-02', 'Staff Transport Expenses', 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (6, '01-01-01', 'Internship Stippends', 4, NULL);
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (7, '01-01-02', 'Non Technical Staff Pay', 4, '1500');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (8, '01-01-03', 'Technical Staff Pay', 4, '5000');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (9, '01-02-01', 'Staff Transport Charges', 5, NULL);
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (10, '01-02-02', 'Daily Product Delivery Transport Charges', 5, '10000');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (11, '02-01', 'East Plant Dues', 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (12, '02-02', 'West Plant Dues', 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (13, '03-01', 'Electricity Bills', 3, NULL);
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (14, '03-01-01', 'Head Office Electricity Bills', 13, '1200');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (15, '03-01-02', 'Plant Electricity Bills', 13, '1300');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (16, '03-02', 'Phone Bills', 3, NULL);
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (17, '03-02-01', 'Mobile Phone Charges', 16, '4500');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (18, '03-02-02', 'Landline Charges', 16, NULL);
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (19, '03-02-03', 'Internet Charges', 16, '2400');
```

It should be like Level 1 for Expenses 2 for Asset and 3 for Bills. I want to group and show the sum of amount separately for each account.

Following is the format I am looking for and I believe this can be done if I group the by level but not sure how to assign level at run time. Also I am not looking for this format in sql window I am creating a report where I can achieve this format if I group them accordingly. So I was hoping if anybody could help me in assigning levels to accounts.

```
ID                                      COACode                                            COATitle                                           ParentCode                              DebitAmount
--------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1                                       01                                                 Expenses                                           NULL                                    NULL
4                                       01-01                                              Salary Expenses                                    1                                       NULL
6                                       01-01-01                                           Internship Stippends                               4                                       NULL
7                                       01-01-02                                           Non Technical Staff Pay                            4                                       1500
8                                       01-01-03                                           Technical Staff Pay                                4                                       5000
                                                                                              ---------------------------------------
                                                                                              6500

5                                       01-02                                              Staff Transport Expenses                           1                                       NULL
9                                       01-02-01                                           Staff Transport Charges                            5                                       NULL
10                                      01-02-02                                           Daily Product Delivery Transport Charges           5                                       10000
                                                                                              ---------------------------------------
                                                                                              10000

2                                       02                                                 Assets                                             NULL                                    NULL
11                                      02-01                                              East Plant Dues                                    2                                       NULL
12                                      02-02                                              West Plant Dues                                    2                                       NULL
3                                       03                                                 Bills                                              NULL                                    NULL
13                                      03-01                                              Electricity Bills                                  3                                       NULL
14                                      03-01-01                                           Head Office Electricity Bills                      13                                      1200
15                                      03-01-02                                           Plant Electricity Bills                            13                                      1300
                                                                                              ---------------------------------------
                                                                                              2500

16                                      03-02                                              Phone Bills                                        3                                       NULL
17                                      03-02-01                                           Mobile Phone Charges                               16                                      4500
18                                      03-02-02                                           Landline Charges                                   16                                      NULL
19                                      03-02-03                                           Internet Charges                                   16                                      2400
                                                                                              ---------------------------------------
                                                                                              6900
```

Comment: give us your expected result. pls assign the levels per record so that we will know how to assign them.

Comment: Expected result is given in the post. If you scroll to the right of the output window you'll see what I am looking for. @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ

Comment: when you do sql, the values are in columns. not all sql have reporting capability. So you want to get the level then do the sum?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ I actually want to group on certain levels. So basically yeah I want to assign levels first then do the grouping and Sum the groups separately.

Comment: go it. i am working on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

```
SELECT 
       COACode,
       COATitle,
       ParentCode,
       DebitAmount,
       Level# AS Level,
       sum(debitamount) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentCode) AS Total
FROM (
      SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentCode ORDER BY COACode) AS Level#
      FROM COA
      ) Tab
ORDER BY COACode
```

**RESULT:**

```
COACode                                            COATitle                                           ParentCode                              DebitAmount                             Level                Total
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------
01                                                 Expenses                                           NULL                                    NULL                                    1                    NULL
01-01                                              Salary Expenses                                    1                                       NULL                                    1                    NULL
01-01-01                                           Internship Stippends                               4                                       NULL                                    1                    6500
01-01-02                                           Non Technical Staff Pay                            4                                       1500                                    2                    6500
01-01-03                                           Technical Staff Pay                                4                                       5000                                    3                    6500
01-02                                              Staff Transport Expenses                           1                                       NULL                                    2                    NULL
01-02-01                                           Staff Transport Charges                            5                                       NULL                                    1                    10000
01-02-02                                           Daily Product Delivery Transport Charges           5                                       10000                                   2                    10000
02                                                 Assets                                             NULL                                    NULL                                    2                    NULL
02-01                                              East Plant Dues                                    2                                       NULL                                    1                    NULL
02-02                                              West Plant Dues                                    2                                       NULL                                    2                    NULL
03                                                 Bills                                              NULL                                    NULL                                    3                    NULL
03-01                                              Electricity Bills                                  3                                       NULL                                    1                    NULL
03-01-01                                           Head Office Electricity Bills                      13                                      1200                                    1                    2500
03-01-02                                           Plant Electricity Bills                            13                                      1300                                    2                    2500
03-02                                              Phone Bills                                        3                                       NULL                                    2                    NULL
03-02-01                                           Mobile Phone Charges                               16                                      4500                                    1                    6900
03-02-02                                           Landline Charges                                   16                                      NULL                                    2                    6900
03-02-03                                           Internet Charges                                   16                                      2400                                    3                    6900
```

Comment: What is the meaning of 5 in  '(order by left(COACode, 5))' ?

Comment: the grouping is meant for the first 5 characters of coacode. For example: level=2 is for all coacode that starts with 01-01*

Comment: This makes sense thank you for the solution. But what if user open more accounts under these accounts. This is dummy data so what if someone opens 03-02-01-01 under 03-02-01 and 03-02-01-01-01 under 03-02-01-01. Will it behave as same and perform right calculations ?

Comment: try it and it will perform the same way.

Comment: If my first answer works for you, then please accept my answer then post another question for your new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
select top 1000 
    *, 
    Level1Sum = sum(DebitAmount) over (partition by left(COACode, 2)),
    Level2Sum = sum(DebitAmount) over (partition by left(COACode, 5))
from COA
order by COACode
```

Comment: I was hoping to assign levels to each Account head.

Comment: This works fine too but I only get upto level 2 heads when I group. I am not seeing Parent code.